# Change size property of an image using a text link

Tags: css, width, mouseover

I am sure this is rediculously simple, but I'm stumped.

Very simply, I want to create a text link that changes the width property of an image on mouse over, and on mouse out, return to the original.

The image I wish to change has an id 'photoimage'

Here's what I have, but it's not doing anything. Any ideas>

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="MM_changeProp('photoimage','','Width','10','IMG')">
photographs
</a>
```

Sorry here is the function

```
function MM_changeProp(objId,x,theProp,theValue) { //v9.0
  var obj = null; with (document){ if (getElementById)
  obj = getElementById(objId); }
  if (obj){
    if (theValue == true || theValue == false)
      eval("obj.style."+theProp+"="+theValue);
    else eval("obj.style."+theProp+"='"+theValue+"'");
  }
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: can we see your `js`?

Comment: What does the `MM_changeProp` function look like?

Comment: @DrydenLong That's a Dreamweaver built-in function.

Comment: have added the functon, didn't spot that!

Comment: do you want to stick with pure javascript or you're ok with using jQuery?

Comment: happy to use either, I just thought it was quite simple, and clearly I'm wrong :-(

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
function setWidth( elementId, width ) {
    var element = getElementById(elementId);
    element.style.width = width; 
}

<a href="#" 
   onmouseover="setWidth('photoimage','200px')" 
   onmouseout="setWidth('photoimage', '100px')"> photographs </a>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought would do it, but I can't get your code to work sadly :-(